# [Putty]Enabling keep alives through the target line

Tags: ssh, putty, file-shortcut

Because I am a (really) lazy person and got bored of entering my login credentials everytime I started Putty, I made a shortcut (I use Windows 8.1 on my laptop) to Putty and appended the target line with my login@host and -pw to do it automatically. My question is if I can do this similarly with keeping my session alive. Because nothing is more frustrating then to find that my session has closed down after a few of minutes of idleness.

Comment: Are you asking what command line parameters to pass to PuTTY to turn on SSH keepalives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Putty.  In the menu on the left select `Connection` in the field for `Seconds between keepalives (0 to turn off)` enter a number, say 45.  In the menu on the left select `Session` select `Default Settings` in the `Saved Sessions` area and click the 'Save` button to the right.

Comment: Thank you. I completely missed the 'Save' button in other posts about this topic (it might be double now). I have done what you asked and opened a session. If it remains open I will mark your answer. One question: What do TCP keepalives do? Should I use that too?

Comment: SO_KEEPALIVE operates at the `transport` level - SSH Keepalives operate at the `application` level.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee470551(v=vs.85).aspx